# Terraform count using bool?

Tags: if-statement, syntax, terraform

`count` is a great meta-argument for being able to provision resources conditionally in Terraform. From my previous experience, we do something like `my_var = "1"` and use this to programmatically control resource creation with `count`.

Since `count` in that case takes in a string `"1"`, but can also interpret a `number` type (e.g. `1`), I'm wondering:

a) What is Terraform's `count` doing under the hood; is it parsing the string as a number first?
b) Can it also accept other data types e.g. `bool`?

I'm hoping to have a `.tfvars` which has a `my_var = true` in it, which is then passed into the `count` meta-argument on affected resources e.g `count = var.my_var`. Is this possible?

---

I also kindly request some information which goes into generally how data types are interpreted in Terraform for "truthiness". If you have docs or a blog post to share it'd be much appreciated!

Comment: `count = var.my_var ? 1 : 0` I think is what you're looking for

Comment: Ternary operator would work, but I'm specifically wondering what will happen if I pass a `bool` into `count` and if that's something that generally "works" in Terraform or not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

a). In Terraform string representation of numeric values are automatically converted to numbers. From the [docs](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/types):

> Terraform automatically converts number and bool values to strings when needed. It also converts strings to numbers or bools, as long as the string contains a valid representation of a number or bool value.
>
> - `true` converts to `"true"`, and vice-versa
> - `false` converts to `"false"`, and vice-versa
> - `15` converts to `"15"`, and vice-versa

This is valid:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3" {
  bucket = "bucket-name"
  count = "1"
}
```

This is also valid:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3" {
  bucket = "bucket-name"
  count = 1
}
```

b). In Terraform booleans are not considered to be numeric values. Numbers are not automatically converted to booleans, which means this is NOT valid:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3" {
  bucket = "asd"
  count = false
}
```

It will throw the following error:

```
╷
│ Error: Incorrect value type
│
│   on main.tf line 9, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3":
│    9:   count = false
│
│ Invalid expression value: number required.
╵
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
variable "disableNewFeature" { default = false }

module "newFeature" {
      count = (var.disableNewFeature)?0:1
}
```

Comment: Yes, this ties everything together; main points are: • Strings can be coerced to numbers *or* booleans so long as the transformation is valid/possible. • Terraform `count` only accepts a number. • You can only provide `count` meta-argument a number which can be accomplished using a ternary operator when using a variable of a boolean type (since a string can be coerced to a number/boolean, but a boolean in HCL cannot be coerced to a number).