# Using tostring() to ensure functional conditionals in Terraform?

Tags: syntax, terraform, conditional-statements

tl;dr: Is it an acceptable practice to use `tostring()` to cast values used for conditionals in Terraform >= 0.13 for handling a strictly defined set of input types?

---

Yesterday I asked a question that led me to a new question today:
[Terraform count using bool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71241451/terraform-count-using-bool)

What I learned is that there is some automatic type-casting applied to certain primitives in Terraform (going to and from strings to other data types mainly), but that these primitives cannot be used to infer a different data type (e.g. a `bool` cannot be passed as an input to the `count` argument because count only accepts a `number` type.

One comment on that question had a very simple way to use a `bool` as a condition:

```
count = var.my_var ? 1 : 0
```

The only potential issue with this, is if `my_var` can have different input types. In my use case, it'll be added to a Terraform module in which the user will decide what to supply for this argument; previously we've only been passing in `string` or `number`, but I find that to be a little less specific than I'd prefer, because Terraform can interpret `count` to be > 1 copy of a resource (I want a discrete 0 or 1 [specifically for something like `var.create_this_resource` whose value can be either true or false]); this also just doesn't look as nice to see `"1"` vs `true` IMO. So I'd like to *start* using `bool` instead, but **also** be able to handle when a user inputs a `number`. What I found is that I can use the following to accomplish this:

```
count = tostring(var.my_var) ? 1 : 0
```

Here, `tostring()` will take whatever is in the input and, presumably, cast it to a string. It only works for `string`, `number`, and `boolean`, and really, I'm only using it to get a `number` to a `string` because that's the only case where passing into a ternary operator is currently failing.

So my question is whether or not it's acceptable to do this? I've tested it with `string`, `bool`, and `number`, as well as unsupported types (i.e. an empty list or `null`); it seems to work well in code but the following made me think I shouldn't use it:

From the [docs](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/tostring):

> Explicit type conversions are rarely necessary in Terraform because it will convert types automatically where required. Use the explicit type conversion functions only to normalize types returned in module outputs.

Comment: It is worth noting that this is true for TF >= 0.12, and that previously bool<-->num casting did work (but it was unwieldy and discouraged). Also, if you are testing the truthiness of a string in the conditional of a ternary, then it would simply need to be non-empty or not `null`. So whether you can do this is one question, but I would have to ask why you are doing this? Also that statement in the documentation is incorrect because all types (even tuples) except for `set` have constructors, so you would need to convert to `set` (unless explicitly type declared).

Comment: Yeah, I'm wondering if I'm having some strange outcomes, since if I pass in `"0" ? "true" "false"` that will evaluate to *false* and if I pass in `"1" ? "true" "false"` (I'm testing this by attempting to create an output). Anything else gives an error stating "The condition of expression must be of type bool." If you have a chance, try it and let me know.

Comment: I'm doing this so I can use `bool` in places it makes sense e.g. `create_my_resource = true` but I also need to have it be backwards compatible or really just flexible with the user's input when calling the module (they should be able to pass `1`, `"1"`, `true`, etc. in and get the discrete outcome).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases I would suggest avoiding designs where a particular variable could have different types in different situations, unless your module is treating the value as entirely opaque and just passing it through to something else which has broader validation rules.

Since your module *is* working directly with this value, it would typically be best to specify an exact type constraint for the variable and make the caller of the module write expressions to convert the value if the automatic conversions are insufficient. That way the caller can get better feedback about what sort of value your module is expecting, and can decide for themselves how to convert their value of a different type.

Converting to string can only produce a value that can automatically convert to `bool` in the following situations:

- The value was already a string, and was either `"true"` or `"false"`.
- The value was a bool value, in which case `tostring` will convert it to a string and then the conditional operator will immediately convert it back to bool again, which would be redundant.

If you declare the variable as being `bool` itself then the same rules will apply, but the conversion will happen inside the calling `module` block rather than in the `count` expression:

```
variable "my_var" {
  type = bool
}
```

```
module "example" {
  # ...

  # This will automatically convert to bool true,
  # just as it would've in the conditional operator.
  my_var = "true"
}
```

---

If you really cannot avoid supporting various unusual ways of writing boolean values then you can potentially write your own conversion table which *would* be based on strings, and would specify the boolean value for each possible string after conversion:

```
locals {
  sloppy_bool = tomap({
    "1"     = true
    "true"  = true
    "0"     = false
    "false" = false
  })

  my_var = local.sloppy_bool[var.my_var]
}
```

Because mapping types (map types and object types) only support strings as keys, `local.sloppy_bool[var.my_var]` will automatically convert `var.my_var` to string, just as if you'd written `tostring(var.my_var)`. It'll then look up the result in the table and return the corresponding boolean value, which means you can then use `local.my_var` instead of `var.my_var` elsewhere in your module and rely on it always being a true boolean value.

I would suggest doing this only if you had a previous version of the module which tolerated this sort of typing weirdness and you need to remain compatible with it. For an entirely new module, I would consider this to be non-idiomatic and probably confusing for anyone already familiar with Terraform who is trying to use the module, because they will need to become familiar with your unusual definition of the type conversion rather than relying on their knowledge of the built-in conversion rules.

Comment: This is a great answer that helps create both an understanding of what to aim for when defining variables, and how to explicitly and objectively handle the situation if backwards compatibility is a must (all in the module's code!)

So, in short, as per the docs, do not use `tostring()` unless there's an output you need that Terraform won't automatically type-cast to.